# server response null when $_POST is used

Tags: php, android, mysql

php code :

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
require "db_conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["pwd"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from user_accounts where user_name like '$user_name' and pwd like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);

if( $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($response,array("user_name"=>$row['user_name'],"first_name"=>$row['first_name'] , "last_name"=>$row['last_na$}
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

//echo json_encode(array("result"=>123));
}else{
echo "login fail";
}

?>
```

I get my response as :
{"server_response":null}

but if i uncomment the sample output and comment the other part i get output as :
{"result":123}

also for some reason instead of $_POST if i were to initialize the variables directly i get the correct output

Comment: How are you accessing the page? Are you sending an HTTP POST request and are supplying user_name and pwd parameters?

Comment: POST request then give both those parameters

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $response is not getting initialized before you use array_push, so $response is still null when you try to echo.